# Type of Hard drive connector

Tags: hard-drive, adapter, connector

Does anyone know what type of connection this is.  I assume its SAS of some type but I have never seen it.  Also if so  what type of adapter should I be looking for. [image]

Comment: What does the label on the drive indicate?

Comment: Looks vaguely like a centronics connector, maybe SCSI. Wikipedia suggests it may be SCA-2

Comment: 68-pin SCA-2 or 3.

Comment: google the make/model of hard drive will tell you.

Comment: Thanks Everyone you are all on track, I was able to find a little more that I stumbled across it is a SCA 2  80  pin SCSI.  Also USB interfaces seem to be a no go  mostly I see only 80 to 68 pin adapters and then maybe to IDE......too many steps for some old drives.  But if somebody knows of a reasonable USB or one step adapter I am all game.

Answer (score 4):

That is one of the various variants of SCSI.
(68-pin SCSI 2 or SCSI 3. Need to see the part-number/model-number of the disk to say for sure.)

SCSI to SATA converters and SCSI to USB converters exist but are VERY expensive.
(It is not a dumb converter. A PCB with conversion chips is required.)

A PCI SCSI controller card is quite cheap (2nd hand), but you also need the cables which can be expensive. Additional problem is finding drivers for such a card as this is old tech. Linux will handle it usually out-of-the-box, but on Windows you may be in trouble.

Usually it isn't worth it to get such an old (and relatively slow, by todays standards) disk working. A brand new SATA disk will be cheaper, faster and bigger.